# Indicating a name change after publication

Tags: publications, cv, personal-name

My wife has publications under both her maiden name and her married name. How should she indicate that this is the case on her CV, if she wants to mention publications from both time periods?

Comment: Jane S. Doe (also known as Jane Smith). I saw this kind of names on CV. Any other ideas?

Comment: @scaaahu We saw that you can use "nee [maiden name]", but idk if that's internationally understood or just an American thing.

Comment: @Tacroy Speaking as someone from Britain, I'm familiar with née. You can find it on gravestones here.

Comment: It may be too late, if she's already published under both names, but one solution is just keep publishing under her maiden name (they don't check your driver's license when you submit an article).  This has its own possibilities for confusion (as does changing your name, as does keeping it), but certainly has been done.

Answer (score 30):

I know 2 female professors personally who clarify this fact very similarly. What they do is this:

1. They cite the relevant publications as they were with her maiden name and her new last name.
2. They add a * at the beginning of the "**Publications**" section in their CV which refers to a footnote to that page which then says something like this "* Last name changed to Smith from Doe in 1988"

That seems to work very well so far.

Answer (score 21):

A short answer, I think one can write

> "full present name", born "maiden name"

or

> "full present name", formerly "maiden name"

and put this in the top of the CV where you have personal details and/or also as a subheading for the publications list.

I also bold face my name in all publications, This way it should not pass anyone where I am in the publications list.

Comment: It's somewhat archaic and may have problems if people don't know what it is, but for brevity and specificity it would be hard to beat "Jane Smith, [née](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nee#English) Doe"

Answer (score 3):

I am in this situation, too. I site my publications as they appear on PubMed, keeping the outdated last name where it is seen on the original aricles. I then underline my full name in each publication, whether it is the current or former last name, i.e. "Jane M. Doe" and "Jane M. Smith" would be underlined in the Publications section. I also have my full, current name at the top of my CV/Resume (i.e. Jane M. Smith) so it is clear that the underlined person (whether Doe or Smith) is me. I have had job coaches indicate they like this strategy.

Answer (score -4):

Unique ID services for authors like ORCID (http://orcid.org/; non-profit) and ResearcherID (http://www.researcherid.com/; associated with Web of Knowledge) are the way to go. You can list all your previous names on your ORCID profile, as well as alternate spellings. Many publishers (including Nature, PLOS, etc) and funders (both in the US and elsewhere) are starting to use ORCID to help manage authors' identities. ORCID suggests placing your ID prominently on your website, CV, and anywhere else folks might encounter your professional identity, to help with name disambiguation.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question, which is how should Jane Doe indicate *on her CV* that the publications listed with author Jane Smith are also hers? People reading a CV aren't going to want to find some website and type an identifier into it.