# Dropping first name for publication

Tags: personal-name

My official name is *Md. Tipu Sultan.* Can I use only *Tipu Sultan* for publishing scientific articles or would there be any problem? I already have published a articles as Tipu Sultan.

Comment: Welcome to Academia SE. I am quite confident that your situation was already asked on this site, though I cannot find it right now. Please take a look at the questions in the [tag:personal-name] tag. If some questions only partially address your problem, please [edit] your question to elaborate what wasn’t addressed (to avoid your question being closed as a duplicate).

Comment: If you've already done it, then you know you can, right...? Am I missing something?

Comment: Yea I can. But as you know some journal ask to put full name during submission. What should i do for that case?

Comment: [This post](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/16333/choosing-my-name-as-an-author-when-publishing-a-scientific-paper-can-i-use-my?rq=1) isn't exactly your question but the answers there should help you. The summary is that you should choose a name to publish under, and publish only under that name. I would interpret a journal's request for a "full name" as referring to your *full published name* in either or both of two ways: 1) They want to make sure you put Tipu Sultan instead of T. Sultan, or 2) They want to make sure you don't only put your surname.

Comment: I'm wondering if in the times of Author IDs as ORCID at least the argument about online databases becomes less relevant.