# My name in publications as an author is different from my name in the passport, how to prove that I'm the same person?

Tags: personal-name

My name in all of my publications is Mohamed Abd El-Ghafour (Abd El-Ghafour, M.) while in passport is Mohamed Abd El-Ghafour Omar, so Abd El-Ghafour is a middle name, is this will be a problem in linking my publications to my passport?
Thank you very much

Comment: In all my years, no academic ever looked into my passport. Also, the difference does not seem to be completely understandable - there is just one name more in the passport, no?

Comment: Not something to worry about. It is more important that all your papers show the same name, however. If you have some with one name and others are different it will just confuse people.

Comment: There have been many similar questions on this site, e.g. https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/16333/choosing-my-name-as-an-author-when-publishing-a-scientific-paper-can-i-use-my.  The short answer is that it is not a problem.

Comment: I guess the OP is asking the question for immigration-related questions. The name discrepancy might invite suspicion of identity theft from custom officers. Note that "Mohammed abd-el-X" is a widespread name pattern in the Arabic world, so homonyms are frequent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would not be worried about the passport having a different name. However, if you want to *claim* the publications as your own, I would setup an [ORCID](https://orcid.org/). That would link them to you and each other. On your ORCID account, list your full name. ORCID also lets you list [other names as well](https://support.orcid.org/hc/en-us/articles/360006973853-Add-and-edit-your-name-on-your-ORCID-record).