# What author name should I use for publication?

Tags: publications, authorship

I'm soon to be co-author for a paper and I'm not too sure which name I should use for publication (like many previous users here!). I have a legal Chinese name which no-one knows me by but is on official documents (passport, my soon-to-be degree certificaet), and my English name which is what everyone calls me and is in the email I use for my CV. Unfortunately both combinations of my legal and surnames are quite popular when I search them on Google (advice I saw given by others) so I'm at a bit of a lost here of what I should do!

I'd really appreciate any advice/thoughts here thank you !

Comment: This has been asked before: Have you tried searching this forum? There's a search bar at the top.

Comment: With with name do you identify more in an academic setting?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Choosing my name as an author when publishing a scientific paper, can I use my "unofficial" first name?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/16333/choosing-my-name-as-an-author-when-publishing-a-scientific-paper-can-i-use-my)

Comment: Sidenote: A group of mathematicians have published under an assumed name for years.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicolas_Bourbaki

Answer (score 0):

**Whichever name you use on your email or, if applicable, professional membership to the journal**.  If a reader contacts NAME and gets a response from OTHER_NAME, it will be a bit jarring and perhaps cause them to wonder if they contacted the correct person.  Similarly, if you are in the journal's system as NAME but your paper uses OTHER_NAME, then that will cause confusion.