# How to request author's name correction in a published paper?

Tags: publications, research-process

I published in the journal "[The International Journal of Advanced Manufacturing Technology (2019) 105:2857–2867,](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00170-019-04444-0)" as "Amir Hussain". However, my name should be corrected to "Aamir Hussain."

I would appreciate the right direction to request this correction to the journal. For instance, who should I contact?

The reason why I didn't notice before, is because I was working in industry and had no plans to come into academia.

Comment: Has this correction been published or are you hoping that it will be? Are you asking what actions you can take?

Comment: I don’t see a question here.

Comment: We can provide advice and answer questions if you provide more information. Otherwise this is likely to be closed.

Comment: @TheDoctor, I think you made assumptions in your edit that may not be warranted.

Comment: @Buffy which assumptions?

Comment: Related: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/10700/how-to-edit-name-on-existing-publications-after-a-name-change

Comment: @TheDoctor, the OP hasn't asked how to edit, nor indicated the reason for this post. Let them speak for themself. Your edit might be fine for a comment.

Comment: This is subject to interpretation. For me the question could be improved but his intent was clear, especially with the reference where you can check that "Amir" is the name used in the publication - so I don't think my edit carried much assumption. But I'll refrain from editing posts from now before asking.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150500/discussion-between-the-doctor-and-buffy).

Answer (score 0):

Contact the journal and ask. The journal website shows the following info:

Production-related enquiries
Queries about accepted manuscripts in production or post-publication corrections should be sent to Igan Dagoy (igan.dagoy@springernature.com).