# How to prove that a paper published with a particular English transliteration of my Russian name is mine?

Tags: publications, personal-name, international

My first name is Евгений (it is Russian; the usual transliteration is Yevgeny). I was born in Ukraine in 1990, when it was still in the Soviet Union, where Russian was the official language. I lived there until 2011, when I went to Canada, where I am currently working on a Ph.D in mathematics. The name indicated in my passport is IEVGEN. It has undergone two rounds of changes: first it was translated from Russian into Ukrainian (Евгений => Євген), and then the Ukrainian version was transliterated into English under the transliteration rules that were valid at the time of receiving the passport. If I received the passport under the present rules, it would be spelled as IEVHEN. The issue here is that the sound in the Ukrainian version is something in between of G and H.

I am deeply unhappy with the "name" IEVGEN: it looks odd, it is not pronounced as the Ukrainian version, and it is definitely not how my parents named me.

I really don't want this spelling to appear on my publications, and ideally even on my Ph.D. thesis. Right now I don't know which version I would prefer, but let's consider YEVGENY, which is the closest to the original, and EUGENE, which is the English/French version of the same name. I know that I am the one who decides under which name to be published, but it raises the following question:

If at some point I will need to prove the authorship of a certain publication that bears a name slightly, or significantly different from what is in my documents, will that be a problem?

EDIT: some of the answers suggest me several ways of how to spell my name, and I appreciate them, but it is not what I have asked. My question only had to do with bureaucratic and juridical aspects of the problem.

EDIT 2: The title of the question was changed by an editor to "What author name to list on publications when English translation of Russian name on passport is unsatisfactory?", which is again completely misleading. I am not asking what to put on publication, I am asking about how to prove that the chosen name corresponds to me. So I edited the title back to the original.

Comment: A note: nowadays some journals (e.g. IEEE journals) support the publication of author names in their native languages.

Comment: Another note: author names are misspelled in databases so often that they generally accept the fact that two different entries can easily be the same person. (Also indispensable for maiden vs. married names.) I've seen at least three forms of my own name, and that's not counting inclusion / exclusion / TeX form / redundant Unicode normalization forms / inventive workarounds for diacritics.

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you considered trying to change the Romanized name in your passport to Yevgeny? I actually have very little idea how hard that would be - have you investigated it?

Comment: @Robert Columbia I hope to get a Canadian passport at some point and have a normal name there. However, I don't see it happening in the observable future. As long as I am a citizen of Ukraine, which lives in the different continent, I believe it is very cumbersome, if at all possible.

Comment: Anecdotally, one of my professors publishes articles and books under her maiden name, which does not appear in her passport at all (both her maiden and her married name are common surnames, too), and it has never caused her any trouble at all, apart from people who know her never quite knowing which name to use when referring to her in written correspondences with other people.

Comment: It'd be so much easier if you could use the same trick as Grigory Perelman - he simply wrote his name as "Grisha". Neat.

Comment: @erz sorry to misconstrue. My main point is that your original title does not reflect your question. A good title should incorporate the context of the question and should stand on its own. I've tried again to capture your question: "How to prove that a paper published with a particular English translation of my Russian name is mine?" Feel free to edit further

Comment: @Jeromy Anglim No worries. Now it's fine.

Comment: Think of publication names as "artists'" names: If most people in research know you as "Chuck Jones" it would be strange to have to look your papers up under "Charles Martin Jones".

Oh, and in the US/Europe/Australia/etc., the name "Yevgeny" isn't so uncommon that people would have trouble dealing with it (some might ask you about your/the name's origins out of curiosity); On the flip side, however, meeting someone called "Eugene" and then finding out later that he's actually called "Yevgeny" in other circles would be strange to me.

Comment: So, it basically boils down to: "Can one publish under pen name and still claim authorship?".

Comment: yes, exactly. The only difference is that it is more like a "pen spelling"

Comment: Small correction: in the Soviet Union, Russian was NOT the official language. There was not an official language,

Comment: Curiously, none of the answers touched the main point of your question: It is very, very, VERY, unlikely that you will ever have to *prove* the authorship  of your papers. If the transliteration of your name on the paper and the transliteration you currently use is even remotely similar (and IEVGEN and Yevgeny definitely qualify), the default assumption is that it's yours. (After all how many people with a similar name work in the exact same field, in that department, at the same time? Also, enough people will remember you giving a talk about it etc.)

Comment: The PhD diploma is a different topic, though; that usually needs to have your official (as in: exactly as it appears on your passport) name -- but it never hurts to ask politely. In your thesis itself, on the other hand, (possibly apart from the very first page), you can pretty much put whatever you want. In particular, it should be possible to put *both* the "official" name (if required) and the original name (even in cyrillic, thank LaTeX) somewhere prominent.

Comment: Finally (sorry for the comment spam), since you mention that you're in mathematics: The semi-official database of papers, MathSciNet, is *very* good at tracking variant names (look at some prominent Russian or Chinese author profiles and their long lists of "also published as" names), so one less reason to worry.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

As a possible solution if you are still worried about it: Get an [ORCID](http://orcid.org/) account.

They basically created an ID, a DOI for researchers. If you link your publications to your ORC-ID, you don't need to worry if your name is very common (e.g. John Smith) or if someone misspelled your name.

Comment: Thank you, I have never heard about it. How "official" is it?

Comment: @erz very! Its quite widespread.

Comment: @erz I think it is pretty well spread. ArXiV for example says it is going to phase out their author ID for ORCID.

Comment: +1 ORCID is an awesome initiative. About how "official" it is, it is not, @erz. But [check the affiliation of the people involved](http://orcid.org/about/community). It is very abrangent. and widespread, indeed.

Comment: @erz I have worked around scientific publishing you can consider ORCID to be close to a standard in the industry, most recent metadata include it. Few notable examples arXiv promotes its usage and Elsevier, Springer and Wiley use it.

Answer (score 69):

Your question has a lengthy introduction, but finally:

> If at some point I will need to prove the authorship of a certain publication that bears a name slightly, or significantly different from what is in my documents, will that be a problem?

No.  A slight difference that can be explained by differences in transliteration is not a problem.  This is not a court case, people working in academia are human.  Some people even change their name completely (in some cultures this was or is common upon marriage) and still they can list articles under both names on their CV.

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by *significantly different* because that doesn't apply here.  Just use the transliteration you prefer.

Comment: If there really is doubt remaining, I would imagine that your intimate familiarity with the publication topic would be sufficient. I would be quite surprised to find a highly knowledgeable person with an uncommon name masquerading as another subject matter expert with a similar name!

Comment: I approve this answer, and would add that publications usually give affiliation together with the name of author. Unless there is another Yevgeny/Eugene/Ievgen with the same last name as you in your department, any question about your authorship (however unlikely they are anyway) will be easily answered.

Answer (score 36):

As mentioned in [other questions](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/78468/348), there’s no need at all for your academic name to match your legal name as indicated on a passport. So go wild.

More generally, Евгений, I would suggest that you take pride in your name, and maybe challenge the Eurocentrism/US-centrism of science a bit by using your original name *in its original spelling*. — At least in addition to a Latinised version.

[I have mentioned elsewhere](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/78468/is-it-possible-to-keep-publishing-under-my-professional-maiden-name-different?noredirect=1#comment192497_78468) that this is unusual: publishers in particular (but also employers etc) really have trouble dealing with names that contain non-ASCII characters, among other things. But this is actually a shame: **Own your heritage**, and don’t let other peoples’ cultural insensitivity force you to forego it completely.

There’s obviously a balance to be struck between practicality and idealism but don’t make it too easy for people to become lazy with foreign names. On a personal note, I find it rather rude how little regard is often paid in the Western world to original names. Science has a diversity problem, and hiding non-Western culture sweeps this problem under the carpet.

Here’s my recommendation in full:

- On your PhD thesis, use your original name and add your preferred Latinised spelling (e.g. Yevgeny) in parentheses.
- In publications and when dealing with employers, at least *try to* make them use your original spelling alongside your preferred Latinised spelling. Don’t be nasty about it but at least make them realise that *they’re inconveniencing you*.
- Use a *consistent* Latinised spelling.
- Acquire an [ORCID](http://orcid.org/) — though, to be honest, its usefulness at the moment is vastly overrated. Most publishers (in my field) flat out ignore it.

These are my recommendations. But the decision which spelling of your name to use is of course yours — *you* have the interpretive authority regarding your own name. Just don’t let that decision be taken away from you by other peoples’ inflexibility and lack of consideration.

---

Anecdote time: [Don Knuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth), one of the most eminent computer scientists, is one of the few authors to use the original spelling of names throughout the bibliography in his *The Art of Computer Programming*. This means Kyrillic, Japanese, Chinese etc. letters. I’ve done the same in my PhD thesis where I could find the original spelling.

Comment: +1 for Own your heritage. I have a fairly European name but with several diacritics and I've been putting it everywhere. Most of what they do is just put it in a database or print it. If their systems can't handle those tasks in Unicode, that's their problem to solve... it's 2016 for heavens' sake.

Comment: @TheVee Ha. Well let's just say that England's oldest University only handles ASCII in its employee database.

Comment: Well, at least I try :-) Of course I respect if there's an explicit request to put in a particular format in a form or if it's automatically rejected. But if the system silently accepts it and breaks later, it's a bug they'll just have to fix, there's no need to be cautious *just in case*.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but it kind of defeats the purpose. The goal is to have a name that satisfies: 1. I like it and associate with myself (at least to some extent); 2. Anybody can read it, memorize and associate with me. And it has to be a SINGLE name, so the presence of another spelling will not contribute... As for taking pride in my heritage, I don't think that mathematics is the right place for that. I don't mind to spell my name in Latin alphabet, I guess I am naturally Eurocentristic. In fact my very name is Eurocentristic, as its version are present in all European languages.

Comment: @erz Like I said, it’s a balance and what importance you put on your heritage/proper spelling of your name etc is obviously solely your own decision.

Comment: Having non ASCII characters in your name shouldn't be a problem nowadays but unfortunately it most certainly is. I can't even count how often I've come across problems because of it. I'd applaud you for trying to use your original spelling but I totally understand if you just decide to use your favorite transliteration everywhere because it saves a lot of trouble.

Comment: While I agree with the sentiment, and can emphasize since one of my native languages is Greek which has its own alphabet, please bear in mind that non-ASCII names are a pain for *everyone*, not just the publishers who are being paid for this. If I have to cite a non-ASCII name in my LaTeX article, I need to include certain packages or escape the accents accordingly or whatever. Yes, the Anglosaxon-centrism implied in ASCII is offensive on the philosophical level, but it does make everyone's life easier to only need to deal with 26 letters and no accents.

Comment: @terdon Until 5–10 years ago I would have agreed. Nowadays you’d get fairly little sympathy from me: there’s enough software (and for developers: libraries) out there that implement Unicode adequately. Case in point, it’s trivial to work with Unicode names in LaTeX. Just copy and paste the name and use a modern LaTeX processor. It’s a question of courtesy to accept this truly minimal inconvenience to get somebody’s name right. (Software developers get even less sympathy: it’s not society’s job to solve programming’s problem, it’s exactly the other way round.)

Comment: @KonradRudolph you'd think so, but it isn't, really. Yes, getting LaTeX to play nice with Unicode is fairly easy (if you know a bit of LaTeX) but getting JabRef to insert Unicode BibTex isn't. The non-ASCII characters keep cropping up where you least expect it. All I'm saying is that the inconvenience is not only to the publishers. It does make things a bit more complicated for everyone. That might not be a good reason to use ASCII, it's just one more thing to take into account.

Comment: @terdon My 100% sincere answer is, then: don’t use JabRef. If a tool is unwilling to implement Unicode in 2016 then it’s crap, and we shouldn’t support it by using it. Not supporting Unicode is completely unacceptable for a text processing tool dealing with names. The point is: this is actively some person’s fault, so we should blame that person rather than setting back society.

Comment: @KonradRudolph but that's just it. Is it JabRef or is it PubMed? Or is it the protocol it uses to communicate? Or is it one journal that screwed up? If *everyone* were using Unicode correctly it wouldn't be a problem, but all it takes is one weak link in a pretty long chain and you get problems. My name is Κάρολος, but I'd rather use Karolos than have to complicate everyone else's life just so I get to see my name in my language.

Comment: @terdon I understand your pain but I advocate making people squirm a little: if no pressure is exerted because everybody wants to avoid inconveniences, things won’t change.

Comment: It's not just the tools. Very few people will know how to pronounce the name, thus nobody will _ever_ remember it when reading, which means they'll just skip over it. Sure, heritage is all good and well, but be considerate to your readers. Maybe if it's a research paper on names in different cultures using the non-Latin characters would be acceptable, but I'd say that in Maths or other science-y fields... just put the Latin spelling. Less extreme example: in Canada my uncle's name is spelt _Harry_. In Finland (where he now lives), it's _Harri_. It's still the same name, despite the spelling.

Comment: Yes, I don't think it is good to use names in Cyrillic in a text in Latin script. Russian names are romanized in western texts and foreign names are transcripted to Cyrillic in Cyrillic written texts. Script is not a languague, one can write Russian in Latin script and English in Cyrillic.

Comment: @VladimirF It’s not a language but it’s a culture. Like I mentioned in a comment above, it’s of course *your* decision how to render your name. Just don’t let fear of inconveniencing other people take that decision away from you. I’ll stress that point in my answer. It’s ultimately about self-determination.

Comment: @KonradRudolph No, it is not just your decision. I have just in my hands a book of abstracts with every abstract in Russian and in English. Every name (no matter if western or Russian) is in Cyrillic in the Russian abstract and is Latin in the English Abstract. It is also the editor's decision. Mixing scripts within a single text is really weird and therefore you can read in newspapers about Барак Обама.

Comment: @FighterJet I went to great pains (and then some) to stress that it’s each individual’s decision. But for what it’s worth I flat out refuse to believe that somebody would forget — or skip over — the name Harry if it were spelled “Harri” (or vice versa). Similarly, I think that a name in a foreign script (alongside its Latinisation) makes that name stand out, rather than forgettable. There are of course well-documented prejudices against foreign-sounding names. But forgettability? No. That’s just not the case.

Comment: @VladimirF And that’s precisely the point I’m attacking here. What you’re describing is true, but it’s chauvinism at worst, and lack of consideration or laziness at best. For that reason I stand by my recommendation: don’t excuse and normalise bad behaviour.

Comment: No, it's a logical and traditional behaviour.

Comment: @VladimirF Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47163/discussion-between-konrad-rudolph-and-vladimir-f).

Comment: This answer and the passionate comments by its author make some valid points... but it's essentially an ideological rant, not an answer to the OP's actual question (except for a couple of helpful suggestions about ORCID etc mentioned also in other answers). So: -1, sorry.

Comment: @DanRomik Well I honestly think you're completely wrong in your assessment, as this answer provides the information OP asked concisely, and the rest is — true, opinionated but — (a) absolutely not a "rant" and (b) highly pertinent information about the culture of authorship identification in science, which underlies an informed discussion of the question.

Answer (score 7):

Orthodox ways:

My first suggestion would be to write "**E. F. Surname**" in the author line of all your papers, with the Latin "E" verbatim, and F being the first letter of your father's name. E.g.: "E. B. Uharikoff" for Евгений Беньяминович Ухариков and "E. O. Bender-Zadunaisky" for Евгений Остапович Бендер-Задунайский. Don't make the mistake to transliterate a middle name such as Беньяминович in full due to an apostrophe having to replace ь: it would cause you endless pain.

As a second choice, the translation of one of the main characters of your dear old Alexander Sergeevich was Eugene Onegin.  You cannot do harm by **Eugene Surname**. Subjectively I like it and I have a friend whose first name is spelt like that on technical documents.

Do use ResearcherID, ORCID, and other means to make sure that you don't lose scientific credit.

Unorthodox way:

If you really wish to stand out: leave it cyrillic **Евгений Фамилия** or even **Жека**/**Жендос**/... (probably even without the surname) on your papers in the author line and provide a footnote with a romanized spelling "Eugene Surname".

Answer (score 6):

I expect you are publishing in English so choose one of the common ways to transcript or transliterate Russian Cyrillic into English latin letters. Some journals will just use the initial E or Y, some will use the full first name. Using one transcription consistently will make it easier for people citing your work.

Others have showed how to connect works published under a different name if that happens.

But if someone will write about you in a different language be prepared that they will use their own transliteration anyway. Jevgenij, Jewgeni, Evgeni, Evgenij, Yevgueni are all common and default ways to transcript Евгений in different European orthographies and using the English transcription in other language sometimes looks very strange.

Using the Cyrillic name in otherwise Latin script name also looks strange, I wouldn't do it. Even in Russian scientific texts the names use the same script as the rest of the text. They are in Cyrillic (even western names!) if the text is in Cyrillic and they are romanized if the text is in the Latin script (usually in the English or other world language).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be known as Eugene in Canada (and in publications), go ahead.  In your CV you can show the alternate spellings you have published under...

> Eugene Onegin (a.k.a. Ievgen Onegin, Евгений Онегин)

Answer (score 1):

The long introduction is important. The answer might differ for academic assessments in different countries. The author might be publishing in two or three different languages with different transliterations suitable to each language (Japanese use Romaji versions of their names for English publications, Kanji versions for Japanese publications).

Digression: All the more reason to use an ORCHID account, and then publish research in the appropriate language and journal,for the appropriate audience. Can audience-targeting-efficiency be given academic credit in publishing impact assessments? Or is it dangerous to use more than one publishing name and dilute the personal brand?

Comment: I am pretty sure its ORC-ID, ORCID

Answer (score 1):

As others have written, it will likely not be a problem for you to argue that it's still you despite the different spelling of the name. I would add an (obvious) reason why this should be the case: No competition; there won't be other claimants of the credit for having written your papers than just you. Well, except in very strange and extreme cases.

Something I would suggest practically, though, is that when you write a paper, a dissertation or what-not, always **include a footnote with the original Cyrillic spelling of your name**. This should typically be rather simple since you already have a footnote with your university/company affiliation - just append to that footnote.

And a second practical suggestion: Why don't you try changing your official  English transliteration of your name to whatever you want it to be? I don't know how these things work in Ukraine but I would think it's possible.

Answer (score -5):

It is quite common for Eastern European people to anglicise their names when settling in English speaking countries.  I had a Hungarian co-worker who was originally named "Szillardi" and he got fed up with people calling him "Mr Salami" so he changed it to "Sillars".  With first names its even a bigger issue.  "Janos" is much harder for most people than "John". So why not change your name to Eugene or even  Gene?

BTW:  Details on changing the name on your passport may be found at https://travel.state.gov/content/passports/en/passports/services/correction.html

Comment: The correct way is to tell people that they should learn to pronounce such a simple name. Janos does not even use phonemes to different from those already present in English (nor does Szillardi, but one must learn that Sz is just /s/.

Comment: If he has a Ukranian passport and is living in Canada, why would he be interested in a page detailing how to change names on a US passport?