# Official name on paper

Tags: authorship

I'm preparing to publish my first paper. I have a question on my name to use on the paper. I'm commonly known as Steve (which I've been using for absolutely everything) but my passport name is my Chinese name (which almost no one knows about). My enrolment is under my passport name. Do I have to use my passport name as the author of my paper?

Comment: Please read [Choosing my name as an author when publishing a scientific paper, can I use my "unofficial" first name?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/16333/546) and [Proving authorship when name in publications does not match name in passport](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/114793/546)

Comment: Thanks, I should have done a search first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't have to use your passport name, use the name you want to publish under. If you search this site, you'll find guidance on selecting a suitable name.

Comment: But select it with care, you want to keep if for a carrer spanning decades.

Comment: @vonbrand Indeed: I've offered guidance before, I just can't remember where