# The name on my article doesn't match my national ID name, and it has already gone into production

Tags: publications, research-process, journals, paper-submission, supervision

I have submitted an article to the International Journal of Surgery, and it has gone into production. Just as I was signing the licensing agreement, it caught my eye that the name I had put in as the main author only contained my surname and my last name. **It did not contain the middle name that is present on my national ID card, as well as my University ID.**

E.g, The name I put in the manuscript: **Wan Teller**

The name on my National ID: **Wan James Teller**

It is a thorough mistake on my part, and I should've paid better attention.

I have no clue what to do now. The deadline to sign the agreement is today. What do I do?

A, Send an email to the producer to change my name in the manuscript **before** signing the licensing agreement.

B, Detail in the email about the mistake and ask the producer to change the name **after** signing the license? **(Note: the license also contains my non-ID name e.g Wan Teller)**

**C, It's not necessary to add the middle name, it's fine if the name on the manuscript doesn't match my ID name.**

Will be tremendously helpful if someone can guide me on this, and quickly.

Comment: The description of option C is correct; see https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/16333/17254 for example. Is that your desired outcome, or do you want the full name spelled out?

Comment: No, I do not want my full name spelled out.

Answer (score 2):

Sign the agreement with your full legal name, *e.g.* Wan James Teller.

If you want the author name in the publication changed, email the editor with that request, but be prepared to be  told that it's too late.

**Edit in response to comments:** In general, a legal agreement should be signed with one's legal name.  My (non-lawyer) opinion is that it won't really matter in this case, but if it were I, I'd use my full legal name.

As others have said, publish with any name you like... with certain limitations like not impersonating others. It's probably best to pick a name and use it consistently on your publications.

Comment: Several other answers here hint that it doesn't matter if I use my national ID name in the paper or not. I do not want to use my middle name. If it wouldn't cause any problems in the future, I would prefer not to use it. If I sign the agreement with my full legal name, it will contrast with the main author name written in the same agreement. Should I still write it?

Comment: @WanTeller Does this ordinarily matter in the place you're from? I don't typically sign my middle name at all except for a couple very very rare cases where the government asks for it; no one else has ever cared or noticed.

Comment: @BryanKrause No it doesn't matter in the place I belong to. I guess I am just worried that the name on the published article will not match the one on my passport, just because I forgot to put in a middle name. I'm worried I might breach a policy by not putting my full name in the article, and they might put down the article later because of it.

Comment: @WanTeller See the post linked by Anyon and many others here like https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/191001/changing-my-legal-name-for-research?rq=1 - you can use whatever name you like for publishing research. Many people choose a particular name because they are known by that name, to simplify long/difficult to pronounce names, to keep a consistent publishing identity after changing name (e.g., due to marriage), etc.

Comment: @BryanKrause Alright, thank you for helping me out.

Comment: Note that the advice is to sign forms with your legal name, but the "author name" on the paper can be different and as you desire.

Answer (score -1):

If your paper has only just gone into production, you should be fine - just tell the publisher when they sent you the proofs that your name is incomplete, and give them the full name. If they have already sent you the proofs (and you approved them), then chances are it is too late, but you can still try. Again, write to the publisher and give them your full name (or whatever name you want to use).

Don't email the editor. This has nothing to do with peer review and is not handled by the editorial board. If the editorial board need to be involved, the publisher will contact them.

Comment: OP said they don't want their full name on the paper.