# Can I use my first and middle names on research publications instead of my first and last names?

Tags: research-topic, online-publication

Can i use my first and middle name as name in research publications instead of first and last name?
Because my full name is long and most people used to call me with first and middle name.

Answer (score 2):

Yes; if fact, you *could* use almost any name you like (!) although there would be few things to be careful about. They are largely covered the answer to [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/191001/changing-my-legal-name-for-research).

One thing particularly worth considering is that if you are likely to publish more in the future, then you might want to register an [ORCiD](https://orcid.org/) which will help you to link your future publications, no matter what name you use.

There are some amusing stories about alternative names, as you might see if your read this story on Wikipedia about the famous [Polymath project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymath_Project), where some papers where published under the "Polymath" pseudonym, and others were not (because the journals refused!).

In addition to the answer on Stackexchange that I have already mentioned, you might like to search the Academia Stack Exchange with the terms

> legal name

where there are a variety of answers to similar, but not identical, questions.